# How to include System.Web.Http.Cors reference dll in .Net Web API

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2013, cors

I'm having a .NET Web API. I wish to make it as CORS Platform. So, I referred
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

In the above link they explained very well how to make the Web API CORS. In the link they are using **`ICorsPolicyProvider`**.

I searched the net for ICorsPolicyProvider, I got a link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.cors(v=vs.118).aspx, in the link they mentioned **`System.Web.Http.Cors Namespace`**

I searched the same in Reference Manager

[image]

Here I can't able to find the **`System.Web.Http.Cors Namespace`**. Kindly assist me how to include the referece **`System.Web.Http.Cors Namespace`**. I think this is a namespace from Microsoft, So, I didn't search in NuGet. Kindly assist me only in Microsoft.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Use Nuget, Microsoft use it for many great things as well.

Go to: TOOLS > Library Package Manager > Package Manager Console, and 
type in:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
```

Reference to the Nuget package [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778469/referencing-system-web-cors)'s another question on this topic

Answer (score 6):

Answer from @Marcus is now outdated, `System.Web.Http.Cors` is no longer comes with `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors` follow this link to install `System.Web.Http.Cors` [Microsoft.AspNet.Cors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34488826/2445111)

Comment: I just installed `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors` and `System.Web.Http.Cors` came with it.

Comment: I installed Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Api.Cors 5.2.6 just now and System.Web.Http.Cors came with it. The link you've pasted in your answer is talking about a different DLL entirely (System.Web.Cors)

Answer (score 0):

I could not include the `Microsoft.AspNet.Cors` package without problems when opening an old project in VS 2022 but after opening it in VS 2019, Shazam!, everything is fine! Maybe you should reinstall the package with `Update-Package -reinstall Microsoft.AspNet.Cors`.